# Listview background not changing

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `viewpager` with a bunch of `listviews` and when the list is not full or empty I want the background to be black where on some phones specifically `motorola` the have the default background as grey

here is my xml with the viewpager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000">

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/top_rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/titlebg"
        android:layout_above="@+id/list">

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgStartupHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fire_android"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:background="#000000"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

and my pager xml that holds the list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:background="#000000">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_rl"
        android:background="#000000" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000">

    </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottombg">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/listName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/incidents"/>   
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in both files I set the background to `#000000` but it is still coming up as the grey background what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, if I set the `listview` to `wrap_content` it shows a black background so the listview background but have something specific to it on certain devices

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a color in the background I had to use a drawable with the color I needed - this way it makes sure that the background color is the same on all devices. Don't forget the   `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

ps I know it's not the most elegant solution - but with Android differences becoming more and more difficult to handle accross so many platforms I tend to use basic easy solutions, that do not allow variations as much as possible.

Comment: I also tried using a drawable for example `@drawable/bg` and that had not effect either :( it was with a .9.png file too

Comment: Then I only see 2 more possibilities: 1. try to set the alpha explicitly when specifying the color or if that doesn't work 2. use an ImageView at the very beginning and for this do fill_parent width + height, fitXY and drawable = your png file - but I really do not understand at all how using a drawable in the background of your layout did not show up - unfortunately I do not have a motorola to test my code :-( . ps did you try in emulator when emulating a motorola? if yes and the problem is the same I could test thses approaches as well...

Comment: I solved it by setting the listview to `wrap_context`, when I did the the background was black which would have been behind the listview so since my list items have a black background it all appears black like I want. It seems the listview background must have something specific to it

Answer (score 0):

please try :

```
android:background="#000000"
android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
```